# What action is my Symfony/Doctrine generated form actually going to?

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

In my Symfony 1.4 project I am using the `doctrine:generate-admin` task to create the modules that compose my backend system. One such module is "journeys". When I view the source of the "journeys/new" page (which displays the form to create a new journey entity) the action of the form is simply "journeys" (I expected it to be "journeys/create"). The "journeys" route on its own would call the `executeIndex` method - however I put a log call in there and upon form submission, the log is not made. So this leads me to believe that `executeIndex` is NOT being called, and another piece of code is being fired upon form submission that then (depending on a hidden input in the form) calls either `executeCreate()` or `executeUpdate()`. Problem is, I don't know where that would be happening. Any insight would be much appreciated.

I don't if this is relevant, but here is the routing definition for the journeys module

```
journey:  
  class: sfDoctrineRouteCollection  
  options:  
    model:                journey  
    module:               journeys    
    prefix_path:          /journeys  
    column:               id  
    with_wildcard_routes: true
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the routes for your journey module (for example using `php symfony app:routes frontend`), you would see that there are 2 actions mapped to the same pattern, but with a different method:

```
journey                   GET    /journey.:sf_format
journey_create            POST   /journey.:sf_format
```

This means that when you do a GET request to /journey the index action is executes, and when you do a POST request the create action is executed.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is routed to `create` action. But you can see the routes that are generated via, e.g.

```
php symfony app:routes frontend
```

You should be able to see which HTTP method maps to which route.